# To update cache automatically, i want to put 'DATETIME' followed by css file name

Tags: css, cache

I want to change the website which can updating new cache by using sort of trick, add the date time next to css file name. This will bust through a browser cache.

But I can not find this format in **/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/head.php**

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfile.css?t=<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" media="screen" />
> ```

you know, i want to put **?t=<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>** this code.
But i don't understand how Magento bring the head meta data and what's going on whatever.

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
/**
 * Initialize template
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/head.phtml');
}

/**
 * Add CSS file to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addCss($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('skin_css', $name, $params);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add JavaScript file to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addJs($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('js', $name, $params);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add CSS file for Internet Explorer only to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addCssIe($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('skin_css', $name, $params, 'IE');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add JavaScript file for Internet Explorer only to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addJsIe($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('js', $name, $params, 'IE');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add Link element to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $rel forward link types
 * @param string $href URI for linked resource
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addLinkRel($rel, $href)
{
    $this->addItem('link_rel', $href, 'rel="' . $rel . '"');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add HEAD Item
 *
 * Allowed types:
 *  - js
 *  - js_css
 *  - skin_js
 *  - skin_css
 *  - rss
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @param string $if
 * @param string $cond
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
{
    if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
        $params = 'media="all"';
    }
    $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
        'type'   => $type,
        'name'   => $name,
        'params' => $params,
        'if'     => $if,
        'cond'   => $cond,
   );
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove Item from HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $name
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function removeItem($type, $name)
{
    unset($this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name]);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get HEAD HTML with CSS/JS/RSS definitions
 * (actually it also renders other elements, TODO: fix it up or rename this method)
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCssJsHtml()
{
    // separate items by types
    $lines  = array();
    foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
        if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $if     = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
        $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
        switch ($item['type']) {
            case 'js':        // js/*.js
            case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
            case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
            case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
                $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
                break;
            default:
                $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
                break;
        }
    }

    // prepare HTML
    $shouldMergeJs = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/js/merge_files');
    $shouldMergeCss = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('dev/css/merge_css_files');
    $html   = '';
    foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
        if (empty($items)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!empty($if)) {
            // open !IE conditional using raw value
            if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                $html .= $if . "\n";
            } else {
                $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>' . "\n";
            }
        }

        // static and skin css
        $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
            empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
            empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
            $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : null
        );

        // static and skin javascripts
        $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
            empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
            empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
            $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : null
        );

        // other stuff
        if (!empty($items['other'])) {
            $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
        }

        if (!empty($if)) {
            // close !IE conditional comments correctly
            if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
                $html .= '<!--<![endif]-->' . "\n";
            } else {
                $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Merge static and skin files of the same format into 1 set of HEAD directives or even into 1 directive
 *
 * Will attempt to merge into 1 directive, if merging callback is provided. In this case it will generate
 * filenames, rather than render urls.
 * The merger callback is responsible for checking whether files exist, merging them and giving result URL
 *
 * @param string $format - HTML element format for sprintf('<element src="%s"%s />', $src, $params)
 * @param array $staticItems - array of relative names of static items to be grabbed from js/ folder
 * @param array $skinItems - array of relative names of skin items to be found in skins according to design config
 * @param callback $mergeCallback
 * @return string
 */
protected function &_prepareStaticAndSkinElements($format, array $staticItems, array $skinItems,
                                                  $mergeCallback = null)
{
    $designPackage = Mage::getDesign();
    $baseJsUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
    $items = array();
    if ($mergeCallback && !is_callable($mergeCallback)) {
        $mergeCallback = null;
    }

    // get static files from the js folder, no need in lookups
    foreach ($staticItems as $params => $rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $name) {
            $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'js' . DS . $name : $baseJsUrl . $name;
        }
    }

    // lookup each file basing on current theme configuration
    foreach ($skinItems as $params => $rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $name) {
            $items[$params][] = $mergeCallback ? $designPackage->getFilename($name, array('_type' => 'skin'))
                : $designPackage->getSkinUrl($name, array());
        }
    }

    $html = '';
    foreach ($items as $params => $rows) {
        // attempt to merge
        $mergedUrl = false;
        if ($mergeCallback) {
            $mergedUrl = call_user_func($mergeCallback, $rows);
        }
        // render elements
        $params = trim($params);
        $params = $params ? ' ' . $params : '';
        if ($mergedUrl) {
            $html .= sprintf($format, $mergedUrl, $params);
        } else {
            foreach ($rows as $src) {
                $html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Classify HTML head item and queue it into "lines" array
 *
 * @see self::getCssJsHtml()
 * @param array &$lines
 * @param string $itemIf
 * @param string $itemType
 * @param string $itemParams
 * @param string $itemName
 * @param array $itemThe
 */
protected function _separateOtherHtmlHeadElements(&$lines, $itemIf, $itemType, $itemParams, $itemName, $itemThe)
{
    $params = $itemParams ? ' ' . $itemParams : '';
    $href   = $itemName;
    switch ($itemType) {
        case 'rss':
            $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link href="%s"%s rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" />',
                $href, $params
            );
            break;
        case 'link_rel':
            $lines[$itemIf]['other'][] = sprintf('<link%s href="%s" />', $params, $href);
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Render arbitrary HTML head items
 *
 * @see self::getCssJsHtml()
 * @param array $items
 * @return string
 */
protected function _prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items)
{
    return implode("\n", $items);
}

/**
 * Retrieve Chunked Items
 *
 * @param array $items
 * @param string $prefix
 * @param int $maxLen
 * @return array
 */
public function getChunkedItems($items, $prefix = '', $maxLen = 450)
{
    $chunks = array();
    $chunk  = $prefix;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (strlen($chunk.','.$item)>$maxLen) {
            $chunks[] = $chunk;
            $chunk = $prefix;
        }
        $chunk .= ','.$item;
    }
    $chunks[] = $chunk;
    return $chunks;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Content Type
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContentType()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['content_type'])) {
        $this->_data['content_type'] = $this->getMediaType().'; charset='.$this->getCharset();
    }
    return $this->_data['content_type'];
}

/**
 * Retrieve Media Type
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMediaType()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['media_type'])) {
        $this->_data['media_type'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_media_type');
    }
    return $this->_data['media_type'];
}

/**
 * Retrieve Charset
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCharset()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['charset'])) {
        $this->_data['charset'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_charset');
    }
    return $this->_data['charset'];
}

/**
 * Set title element text
 *
 * @param string $title
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->_data['title'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix') . ' ' . $title
        . ' ' . Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_suffix');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve title element text (encoded)
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['title'])) {
        $this->_data['title'] = $this->getDefaultTitle();
    }
    return htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(trim($this->_data['title']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}

/**
 * Retrieve default title text
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDefaultTitle()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_title');
}

/**
 * Retrieve content for description tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['description'])) {
        $this->_data['description'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_description');
    }
    return $this->_data['description'];
}

/**
 * Retrieve content for keyvords tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKeywords()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['keywords'])) {
        $this->_data['keywords'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_keywords');
    }
    return $this->_data['keywords'];
}

/**
 * Retrieve URL to robots file
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRobots()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['robots'])) {
        $this->_data['robots'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_robots');
    }
    return $this->_data['robots'];
}

/**
 * Get miscellanious scripts/styles to be included in head before head closing tag
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getIncludes()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
        $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
    }
    return $this->_data['includes'];
}

/**
 * Getter for path to Favicon
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFaviconFile()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['favicon_file'])) {
        $this->_data['favicon_file'] = $this->_getFaviconFile();
    }
    return $this->_data['favicon_file'];
}

/**
 * Retrieve path to Favicon
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getFaviconFile()
{
    $folderName = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image_Favicon::UPLOAD_DIR;
    $storeConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/shortcut_icon');
    $faviconFile = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;
    $absolutePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/' . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;

    if(!is_null($storeConfig) && $this->_isFile($absolutePath)) {
        $url = $faviconFile;
    } else {
        $url = $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico');
    }
    return $url;
}

/**
 * If DB file storage is on - find there, otherwise - just file_exists
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isFile($filename) {
    if (Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->checkDbUsage() && !is_file($filename)) {
        Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->saveFileToFilesystem($filename);
    }
    return is_file($filename);
}
}
```

how can i edit it?

Comment: Not an answer, but it is already done and IMHO reinventing a wheel is not a best idea. 
https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_JsCssTstamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a local override/rewrite or whatever you prefer, be ready to make modifications to the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head:: _prepareStaticAndSkinElements` method.

You *probably* don't want your cache buster to use the current time on every page refresh, otherwise the standard asset caching on the browser end will be useless as every page will be showing the same version of the css file, but with a different name.

What you can do however, is make the asset version tied to a file which you can manually increment on every deployment. This way the browser caching works, unless you want to bust everyones caches when you deploy a new css change.

At the end of the the `_prepareStaticAndSkinElements` function you can modify it to look like

```
    $version = file_get_contents(BP . DS . 'assetversion.txt');

    $html = '';
    foreach ($items as $params => $rows) {
        // attempt to merge
        $mergedUrl = false;
        if ($mergeCallback) {
            $mergedUrl = call_user_func($mergeCallback, $rows);
        }
        // render elements
        $params = trim($params);
        $params = $params ? ' ' . $params : '';
        if ($mergedUrl) {
            $html .= sprintf($format, $mergedUrl, $params);
        } else {
            foreach ($rows as $src) {
                if ($version) {
                    $src.='?v=' . $version;
                }
                $html .= sprintf($format, $src, $params);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will get the contents of the file `assetversion.txt` which you will store in your project root, this can contain the number "1" to begin with. It will then append this as a `?v=1` parameter to all asset urls on the page.

When you next make a CSS change and need to bust through browser cache, simply increment the number in this text file then flush your magento caches.

Comment: I strongly recommend this solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

First things you are cannot use **ASP code** in **Php file**

```
<%=DateTime.Now.Ticks %>
```

change to Php code

```
<?php echo strtotime("now"); ?>
```